# Transfer of files and apps from old sd card to new sdcard

Tags: app2sd

I have got a new 8 GB SD card, but the catch is I have done the app2sd stuff. So what are the steps to be followed for the data and apps transfer without loss of anything.

Will a simple copy and paste including all hidden files be enough?

Comment: apps2sd? The default one or one where you save stuff to the ext partition?

Comment: If you just copy on Windows/Linux/MacOs, everything will be fine. I.e.there is a (on your phone) hidden .android_secure folder which contains the app2sd data (hidden on the phone) that you just can copy using anything different than your phone.

Comment: the default free app i downloaded

Comment: thanks ce4, just copied as you said and its working fine...thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on how the copy is performed. The SD card contains a couple of hidden files/directories (especially with App2SD being used, there's the `.android_secure` folder to be considered).

Usually, when on a Linux workstation, a complete copy from sdcard#1 to sdcard#2 should do the job (`cp -dpR <source> <target>`). Same should apply to Mac OS. As I have no Windows, I cannot speak for that.

Comment: What about creating the second partition for app2sd? Doesn't app2sd make any difference to regular sd card clone?

Comment: I don't know how you create a second partition for App2SD. Usually, as far as I know, App2SD just creates encrypted containers on the sd card. Never heard a separate partition is automatically created or required -- though apps like Link2SD recommend this and make use of them, stock App2SD usually does not -- again, as far as I know. Not sure whether there are special implementations around. Is your original card partitioned?

Comment: It also works on windows, but you have to make all hidden files and folders visible.