# How to change SD Card after moving apps using Link2SD?

Tags: sd-card, link2sd

I haven't used Link2SD yet to move apps, because there is one thing I'm confused about. Currently, I have a 2 GB SD card on my phone, but I'm thinking to buy another 8 GB card later.

What will I have to do if I want to transfer all the apps (linked/moved using Link2SD) to my new 8 GB SD card?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Transfer of files and apps from old sd card to new sdcard](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27510/transfer-of-files-and-apps-from-old-sd-card-to-new-sdcard)

Comment: @IAmTheSquidward This isn't a duplicate, since App2SD and Link2SD use different methods, and the answer given is only relevant for App2SD.

Comment: But that's not what I'm looking for. That method is for Moving files using Linux and MAC. What about Windows? and What about the Second partition?

Comment: [How to move 7GB ext4 partition on external SD card to 30GB partition on another SD card?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/220006/218526)

Answer (score 0):

I tried copying the SD card to a folder and then to the new card. I used Linux Mint 17 running Nemo as root. If you don't have Linux installed, I would recommend a Kali Live disc, since it runs as root.

Everything seems to have been copied, but the first boot of the phone gave me an inconsistent UID message. It was gone at second boot. Some apps worked, some worked after reinstalling, and others lost all of their data.

If you try this, move the stuff you really don't want to lose back to the phone. Starting a game all over again when you were at level 200 really bites. Facebook and Messenger store everything on servers, so they could be easily reinstalled.

Answer (score -1):

When you want to change your SD card from 2GB to 8GB, you should have two partitions on the 8GB SD card.

First of all, uninstall all of your non-system apps and open Link2SD.
Select clean up SD partition 2 and then select cleanup partition's Dalvik-cache. Now you can insert a new SD card and enjoy these features without any issue.

Answer (score -1):

Its a simple procedure really. All you have to do is connect your SD card via a reader or adapter to a computer. Then copy all the data to a folder. Then transfer all they data to your new SD card and it should work.

This method is not exactly foolproof so don't delete the data from the first card in case you need it

Comment: It's not that simple since in the original card there are two partitions, and most probably one of them is formated in ext2 or ext3. That partition won´t be readable for Windows. So unless your computer is Linux, you need utilities that can deal with that