# Can we change SD card after installing a custom rom?

Tags: custom-roms

i have Samsung gt-19082 i recently rooted my phone and added cosmic cm 11, but i have a smaller SD card ? i want to know is it safe to change the SD card ? (as during installation we add all the ROM , g apps on the SD card . i am a newbie at this

Comment: Whenever your device is off, you surely can remove and change.

Comment: Think about files that you placed on SD card while flashing ROM as .exe for installing a program on windows. Files are placed there and have instructions where they go. After installing you can delete it without any consequences. And yes you can change your SD card without problems

Answer (score 0):

**For TL;DR** It is definitely safe to replace your external SD card for a new one.

A normally working system will continue working normally. However there is no guarantee that all your apps will work correctly, as some of them may store extra info on your external SD card, like image caches (this is different from normal caches, some caches regenerate but others don't, e.g. image cache from the most popular instant messaging app in China, WeChat) and [Link2SD](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/78707). Most apps are designed to store only 'unessential' data on external SD card, so there's just a small matter of some network traffic to reload those caches.