# How to move 7GB ext4 partition on external SD card to 30GB partition on another SD card?

Tags: external-sd, file-system, partitions, link2sd

I had rooted my Android Lollipop 5.1.1  phone and installed Link2SD and linked installed apps on `ext4` 7GB 2nd partition of external SD card of 16GB size . The apps installed occupied 6.5GB space and I am getting low space now. I got 64GB external SD card and want to dedicate 30GB.

I created image of 7GB 2nd partition of external SD card through following command:

```
dd bs=4k count= if=/dev/block/mmcblk1p2 | gzip -5 -c > /storage/sdcard1/sdcard2root.img.gz
```

Now whats the way to clone this image to a 30GB partition?

Comment: note that (gzip) compression only works on */dev/block/dm-0* (but not actually on */dev/block/mmcblk0p30*) because of encryption

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy to achieve on a Linux PC:

- Attach both SD cards to PC.
- Dump 2nd partition from old SD card to new one. It's also possible directly from Android device. See [Creating Partition Dump](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/208114/218526).
- Resize filesystem size to 30GB (the new partition size) using `resize2fs`.

### COPY WHOLE FILESYSTEM:

The above approach works on Android too if you are able to attach new SD card through USB OTG SD card reader, while the old one is inside phone.

Or you can do it in 2 steps, as you are already trying:

- Create partition dump:

  ```
  ~# gzip -9ck /dev/block/mmcblk1p2 >/storage/sdcard1/sdcard2root.img.gz
  ```

  You can use `dd` or `cat` or even `cp`. Make sure you have enough space on primary external (physically internal) storage to save dumped (and optionally compressed) image of SD card's 2nd partition.

  Compression is useful only with sparseness. To avoid copying freed filesystem blocks (of deleted files) use `e2image -rap`. Or discard logical to physical block mapping using `fstrim` (on mounted filesystem) or `e2fsck -E discard`, and drop page cache using `sync; echo -n 1 >/proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`.
- Insert new SD card and do partitioning using `parted` or `gdisk` or `fdisk`.
- Write partition image to new SD card:

  ```
  ~# gzip -dck /storage/sdcard1/sdcard2root.img.gz >/dev/block/mmcblk1p2
  ```
- Maximize filesystem size to partition size:

  ```
  ~# resize2fs /dev/block/mmcblk1p2
  ```

---

### COPY FILESYSTEM CONTENTS:

Another method is to only copy/move filesystem contents (files, directories etc.) and not the whole filesystem structure. But files' metadata needs to be preserved, or things may break (since the partition is to be mounted inside `/data`). It includes `timestamps`, permission `mode`, `owner`, `group` and `extended attributes`, particularly SELinux contexts. Some executable binaries (in `/system`) might also have file capabilities set (saved as extended attributes) but that's usually not required for user data. Other metadata like ACLs (also saved as extended attributes) and file attributes ([inode flags](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout#Inode_Table)) are not generally used on Android devices.

On Linux tools like `rsync` (or even `cp`) can preserve the required metadata. For reference see [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/44253/262728) and [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/118840/262728) answer. On Android (to move the contents in 2 steps) `tar` is a good choice:

```
~$ cd /path/to/old_sdcard/mountpoint/
~$ tar --create --preserve-permissions --selinux --verbose --gzip --file=/storage/sdcard1/sdcard2root.tar.gz .
```

Insert new SD card, do partitioning (if required), and create filesystem using `mkfs.ext4` (by default it takes whole partition). To restore backup:

```
~$ cd /path/to/new_sdcard/mountpoint/
~$ tar --extract --preserve-permissions --selinux --verbose --gunzip --file=/storage/sdcard1/sdcard2root.tar.gz
```

Comment: thanx for answering  i will  try it  and let you know i have windows  so i cant try  linx option but will try  e2image or dd commands thanx a lot again

Comment: Android tar binary doesn’t have selinux option. So is busybox.

Comment: @KhurshidAlam https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/exe-static-linux-binaries-for-arm-android-cryptsetup-encfs-f2fs-tools-testdisk-photorec.3709380/page-8#post-79825447

Comment: @IrfanLatif Thanks. But how do you install those ? Adb push /system/bin ? Wouldn’t it overwrite existing  ?