# How to upgrade to a new micro SD card?

Tags: sd-card

I have a 16 GB SD card and would like to upgrade to a larger one
How do I do so without losing any data?

Most of my search results for this just end up advertising a 3rd party program
There are just so many n I don't feel like going through each of them until one works
I'd like to not mess with the SD card in my phone until I have to

Comment: The answer to this question would vary greatly based on whether your current microSD card is used as Adopted (Internal) storage or Removeable (External) storage... If it's removeable storage, it is literally just remove the old card, insert the new card and format it as removeable, then using a PC copy the contents of the old card to the new card and insert it into the phone and you're done. If it's adopted storage, it's a bit more difficult and in depth.

Comment: Related: [How to move 7GB ext4 partition on external SD card to 30GB partition on another SD card?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/220006/218526)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm quoting someone who gave the correct answer as a comment
I had already done this since I was trying to figure it out on my own as well
But they worded it better than I could have

> If it's removeable storage, it is literally just remove the old card,
> insert the new card and format it as removeable, then using a PC copy
> the contents of the old card to the new card and insert it into the
> phone and you're done

2020 approved