# How to resize SD card using terminal? and create a new partition on it?

Tags: sd-card, partitions, terminal

I don't have SD card reader for my computer, so maybe I could do it directly from termux instead.

How to resize SD card without losing data? And make new EXT4 partition.

`(parted) p`:

```
Disk /dev/block/mmcblk1: 63.9GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  63.9GB  63.9GB  primary               lba
```

Comment: See `sgdisk` example here: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/220042/218526

Comment: Related: [How to move 7GB ext4 partition on external SD card to 30GB partition on another SD card?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/220006/218526)